# How to map a discrete variable to a continuous color scale in plotly express

Tags: python, plotly

I'm looking to define an order to a categorical variable and leverage a continuous color scale for the color of each line. Below is my code that is currently producing an error. Can anyone help me achieve this, or is this not possible?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'],
                   'group':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                   'val':[3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7,  3]})

df['group'] = pd.Categorical(df['group'], ordered=True, categories=['a', 'b', 'c'])

px.line(df,
        x='dt',
        y='val',
        color='group',
        color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Blues)
```

Current error message: TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color_continuous_scale'

Comment: _"currently producing an error"_: What error?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color_continuous_scale'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line), there is no `color_continuous_scale`, but there is `color_discrete_sequence`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'],
                   'group':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                   'val':[3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7,  3]})

df['group'] = pd.Categorical(df['group'], ordered=True, categories=['a', 'b', 'c'])

px.line(df,
        x='dt',
        y='val',
        color='group',
        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Blues)
```

[image]